# Getting Issue with installing via. apt-get

Tags: apt, graphics, macbook-pro

sudo apt-get install swi-prolog

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgbm1-lts-vivid : Depends: libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-vivid (= 10.5.2-0ubuntu1~trusty1) but 10.5.9-2ubuntu1~trusty2 is to be installed
 swi-prolog : Depends: swi-prolog-nox (= 6.6.4-2ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: swi-prolog-x (= 6.6.4-2ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
anuj@anuj-MacBookPro:~/Desktop$ 

    E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Apt-get is not working for me. I am using Mactel , Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I recently switched from x.org graphics driver to nvidia drivers. Been having this issue since then.

`libgbm1-lts-vivid : Depends: libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-vivid (= 10.5.2-0ubuntu1~trusty1) but 10.5.9-2ubuntu1~trusty2 is to be installed` 
This is the error message i'm getting.

And `sudo apt-get -f install` is also not working.

`cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list | grep ppa` returns

```
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome-terminator/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome-terminator/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/gwibber-daily/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/gwibber-daily/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/jfi/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/jfi/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/mactel-support/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/mactel-support/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/mactel-support/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/mactel-support/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/marutter/rdev/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/marutter/rdev/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu trusty main
```

Comment: Can you tell me what method you used to install the Nvidia drivers? Did you install it using the website script/download? If you followed some instructions please share the link to those instructions.

Comment: I had x.org drivers installed. I used the Additional Drivers to install the Nvidia 340 driver.

Answer (score 0):

## Perform an Update

Enter command `sudo apt-get update` and try again.

## Else Remove PPAs

If it doesn't work then I bet it is a conflict with a ppa that is requesting an old version of the library. 
If at some point you added a ppa to install `swi-prolog` then:

1. Remove the ppa.
2. Update repository.
3. Try to install again.

It is possible a ppa for a different program could be the problem but I doubt it. Since tyring to installed the program is requesting the older version of the library `10.5.2-0ubuntu1~trusty1` compared to `10.5.9-2ubuntu1~trusty2` that "is to be installed", then you probably have a ppa that is installing an old version of the program with old libraries.

## Alternatively

Check this very informative [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa).

Let me know if nothing works and we can try something else. Sometimes during upgrade some files are not correctly updated and we can take a look.

Comment: Nope, tried that. I have disabled all the ppa for the time being. apt-get -f install leads to The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libegl1-mesa-lts-vivid : Depends: libgbm1-lts-vivid (>= 7.11~1) but it is not going to be installed
 xserver-xorg-core-lts-vivid : Depends: libgbm1-lts-vivid (>= 8.1~0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: I tried updating the broken package through synaptic but same issue there. I can install new packages from synaptic though.

Comment: Even if you disabled the ppa you may still have the old library installed. Execute this `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list | grep ppa` and show me the output. Enclose the out put with \` output \` so it looks like this `output` and add it to your question, might be relevant to your case.

Comment: Okay. Updated.                                                        !

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I tried to delete `libgbm1-lts-vivid` using `dpkg -r --force-depends libgbm1-lts-vivid`. It deleted the package. Then I switched back to Synaptic. Now there were 2 broken packages instead of 1. I selected them for removal. Then, it deleted all of the dependencies that included the nvidia drivers, and re-installed x.org graphics drivers.

The `apt-get -f install` problem seems to be solved but I am back to x.org nouveu drivers instead of nvidia ones. Will look to reinstall nvidia drivers again. Hope it doesnot lead to the same issue.

Thx Torrien.